# Insert a dictionary with list values to the database in web2py

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

Hello i have ajax posting data to my controller like below

`<Storage {'transaction_charge': ['1100', '1100'], 'min_amount': ['10000', '20001'], 'max_amount': ['20000', '50000'], 'admin_charge': ['1500', '3000'], 'other_charge': ['30', '60']}>`

I can safely convert this to a dictionary whose key values are lists like below

`{'transaction_charge': ['1100', '1100'], 'min_amount': ['10000', '20001'], 'max_amount': ['20000', '5000'], 'admin_charge': ['1400', '3000'], 'other_charge': ['80', '70']}`

I also have a database table with names matching key names in the above data set, 
I would like to post this to the database in such a way that each list value creates a new record
in the database, 
e.g

```
id | min_amount | max_amount | admin_charge | transaction_charge | other_charge
1  | 10000      | 20000      | 1500         | 1100               | 30
2  | 20001      | 50000      | 3000         | 1100               | 60
```

**NOTE** my table fields are dynamic, they may change if a user adds another charges type, so i don't want to explicitly add these records,
Is there a way web2py can be smart enough to read these keys, and map their list values to table columns in some kind of loop so it creates `len(ajax_data['key')` records in the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, web2py has a nice way of filtering a dictionary to only include  keys that match a table's fields: _filter_fields

You'll want to transform your posted data from a dict of lists to a list of dicts, e.g.:

```
data = [
  {
    'transaction_charge': '1100', 
    'min_amount': '10000', 
    'max_amount': '20000', 
    'admin_charge': '1400', 
    'other_charge': '80', 
  },
  {
    'transaction_charge': '1100', 
    ...
  }
]
```

Then you can loop, filter, and insert:

```
for row in data:
  db.table_name.insert(**db.table_name._filter_fields(row))
```

Comment: Owkay i honestly hadn't thought of this, thanks let me give it a try.